# How to prevent UITableView from scrolling down?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

How can I prevent the UITableView from scrolling  down only?
I tried to use scrolling enabled property but its freeze the scrolling from both sides.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false  works cleanly

Comment: Thanks,  exactly what I ment

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` in your `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 {
        // you scrolled down
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false` in your `viewDidLoad()` method.

This will help you achieve what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `view-controller` as your `UITableView`'s delegate

```
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
```

and add the following method to your view-controller,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];

    if(translation.y > 0){
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I guess it would work.

**Edit:** I am sorry I didn't see the tag the last time. Here's the Swift version:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var translation: CGPoint = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview)

    if translation.y > 0 {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    } else {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   myTableView.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 && scrollViewmyTableView.scrollView) 
    {
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    }
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```